# I wanted to hover a DIV and make another image rotate

Tags: html, css

I wanted to hover a `<div>` and make another to image rotate. My code is not giving me the expected results.

HTML

```html
<section id="space">
    <div id="falcon">
        <div id="w" class="directors"><p>&raquo;</p></div>
        <div id="ne" class="directors"><p>&raquo;</p></div>
        <div id="n" class="directors"><p>&raquo;</p></div>
        <div id="se" class="directors"><p>&raquo;</p></div>
        <div id="s" class="directors"><p>&raquo;</p></div>
        <div id="sw" class="directors"><p>&raquo;</p></div>
        <div id="e" class="directors"><p>&raquo;</p></div>
        <div id="nw" class="directors"><p>&raquo;</p></div>
        <img id="rocket" src="C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\Foundation booster\CSS\imgs\rock.png" alt="rocket">
    </div>

</section>
```

CSS

```css
#w:active ~ div:nth-of-type(9) ~ #rocket {
    transform: rotate(-0.25turn);
}

#ne:active ~ div:nth-of-type(8) ~ #rocket {
    transform: rotate(0.125turn);
}

#n:active ~ div:nth-of-type(7) ~ #rocket {
    transform: translatey(-30px);
}

#se:active ~ div:nth-of-type(6) ~ #rocket {
    transform: rotate(0.375turn);
}

#s:active ~ div:nth-of-type(5) ~ #rocket {
    transform: rotate(0.5turn);
}

#sw:active ~ div:nth-of-type(4) ~ #rocket {
    transform: rotate(-0.375turn);
}

#e:active ~ div:nth-of-type(3) ~ #rocket {
    transform: rotate(0.25turn);
}

#nw:active ~ div:nth-of-type(2) ~ #rocket {
    transform: rotate(-0.125turn);
}
```

I want `#rocket` (an image) to rotate on when I hover over each div above it. My method actually works on first 4 `<DIV>` (from N to SE). But it won't work for the last four DIVs (S to NW).
I simply can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was a bit unclear so I hope this is what you mean by saying
 *"I wanted to hover a div and make another to image rotate"*

```css
.directors {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#rocket{ transition:50ms; }

#w:hover ~ #rocket {
  transform: rotate(-0.25turn);
}

#ne:hover ~ #rocket {
  transform: rotate(0.125turn);
}

#n:hover ~ #rocket {
  transform: translatey(-30px);
}

#se:hover ~ #rocket {
  transform: rotate(0.375turn);
}

#s:hover ~ #rocket {
  transform: rotate(0.5turn);
}

#sw:hover ~ #rocket {
  transform: rotate(-0.375turn);
}

#e:hover ~ #rocket {
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
}

#nw:hover ~ #rocket {
  transform: rotate(-0.125turn);
}
```

```html
<section id="space">
    <div id="falcon">
        <div id="w" class="directors">W</div>
        <div id="ne" class="directors">NE</div>
        <div id="n" class="directors">N</div>
        <div id="se" class="directors">SE</div>
        <div id="s" class="directors">S</div>
        <div id="sw" class="directors">SW</div>
        <div id="e" class="directors">E</div>
        <div id="nw" class="directors">NW</div>
        <img id="rocket" width='32' src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/431/431302.png" alt="rocket">
    </div>
</section>
```

### Why your code doesn't work:

hover each button to see which `div` actually gets selected (using your selectors). That is because the `nth-of-type` is incorrect (and also irrelevant to what you're trying to achieve).

At `s` and beyond the `nth-of-type` cannot work because `s` itself is `nth-of-type(5)` so `#s:hover  ~ div:nth-of-type(5)` makes no sense, and also all the next ones.

```css
#w:hover  ~ div:nth-of-type(9) { background: gold; }
#ne:hover ~ div:nth-of-type(8) { background: gold; }
#n:hover  ~ div:nth-of-type(7) { background: gold; }
#se:hover ~ div:nth-of-type(6) { background: gold; }
#s:hover  ~ div:nth-of-type(5) { background: gold; }
#sw:hover ~ div:nth-of-type(4) { background: gold; }
#e:hover  ~ div:nth-of-type(3) { background: gold; }
#nw:hover ~ div:nth-of-type(2) { background: gold; }

.directors {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section id="space">
    <div id="falcon">
        <div id="w" class="directors">W</div>
        <div id="ne" class="directors">NE</div>
        <div id="n" class="directors">N</div>
        <div id="se" class="directors">SE</div>
        <div id="s" class="directors">S</div>
        <div id="sw" class="directors">SW</div>
        <div id="e" class="directors">E</div>
        <div id="nw" class="directors">NW</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for replying...
wow it's your code is giving what the result I wanted
I would be so thankful if you answer these two questions
so the nth-of-type() function is useless...????
Do u have any idea why the first dives (W,NE,N,SE) are working (giving the same results as yours) while the last 4 dives (S,SW,E,NW) are not working in my coding ?
Once again thanks for stopping by to reply....

Comment: @AkashWelgama - I've added to my answer the reason why your selectors don't work

Comment: To be honest it was now I was able to understand...thanks very much for replying...
Good luck !!!

Comment: @AkashWelgama - you should mark it as answered if this helped you solve the issue

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not that familiar with stack overflow...
Please could you tell me how to mark it as answered?

Comment: @AkashWelgama - [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)